# vector<string> or vector<char *>?

Tags: c++, string, visual-studio-2008, pointers, char

**Question:**

- What is the **difference** between:

  - `vector<string>` and `vector<char *>`?
- How would I pass a value of data type: `string` to a function, that specifically accepts:

  - `const char *`?

For **instance**:

```
 vector<string> args(argv, argv + argc);

 vector<string>::iterator i;

 void foo (const char *); //*i
```

- I understand using `vector<char *>`: I'll have to copy the data, as well as the pointer

#### Edit:

Thanks for input!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with vectors specifically.

A `char*` is a pointer, which may or may not point to valid string data.

A [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) is a string class, encapsulating all the required data that makes up a string, along with allocation and deallocation functionality.

If you store `std::string`'s in a vector, or anywhere else, then everything will *just work*.

If you store char pointers, you have to do all the hard work of allocating and freeing memory, and ensuring the pointers only ever point to meaningful string data, and determine the length of the strings and so on.

And since `char*`'s are expected by a lot of C API's as well as part of the C++ standard library, the `string` class has the `c_str()` function which returns a `char*`.

Comment: VC compiler error: "cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char to LPCSTR' - function PathFileExistA

Comment: *i->c_str() //any suggestions?

Comment: @Atklin: Remove the leading *.

Comment: You can also use { string str = "test"; const char* myTest = str.data(); }

Answer (score 3):

To pass a `string` to something expecting `const char *`, use the `string`'s `c_str()` member, which returns a null-terminated string:

```
string s = "foobar";

int n = strlen( s.c_str() );
```

Answer (score 3):

`char*` is actually a pointer to a value of type `char`, which defines what can and can't be done with that value. You could make an `int* number` and `number` references the pointer to the block of memory where this value is stored, and will assume it is an `int` and will lock in that type for that memory block. But you can store a `char` `'C'` in that memory block but it will throw a compilation error because it says you cant perform those `int` functions on that `char`.

Answer (score 1):

```
foo(i->c_str());
```

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/ :

> String objects are a special type of
>   container, specifically designed to
>   operate with sequences of characters.
>
> Unlike traditional c-strings, which
>   are mere sequences of characters in a
>   memory array, C++ string objects
>   belong to a class with many built-in
>   features to operate with strings in a
>   more intuitive way and with some
>   additional useful features common to
>   C++ containers.

`char*` is a pointer to a character, nothing more.

You can use the `c_str()` to pass data that is required as `const char*`.

As for copying, if you copy the data you will have a new location for the string, and therefore a new pointer.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `vector< string >`, only because finding would be value based and not address based. However, `vector< char* >` would be faster, so each has its benefits.

Answer (score 1):

`vector<char *>`  sounds like a bad idea!! Unless your programm is running in a memory limited system.